# How to download files in Google Cloud Storage using rest api

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-apps

Scenario: there are multiple folders and many files stored in storage bucket related to dcm API.(click,impression,daily aggregate files etc).
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/dcmaccountno

Is it possible to download files using rest api and currently i have service account and private key. 
we dont have much exposure towards goog cloud storage hence any small help would be really appreciable.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do calls to whichever of the two REST APIs: JSON or XML. In any case, you will need to get an authorization access token from OAuth 2.0 as detailed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing) and then use cURL with a GET Object Request:

**JSON API:**

```
curl -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -o "[SAVE_TO_LOCATION]" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[OBJECT_NAME]?alt=media"
```

**XML API:**

```
curl -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -o "[SAVE_TO_LOCATION]" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]"
```

Note that for multiple files, you will have to program the requests, so if you want to easily download all the objects in a bucket or subdirectory, it's better to use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) instead.

Comment: Thanks Neri i went through this doc however have a doubt on [OAUTH2_TOKEN].

Comment: The OAuth2_token is the one you get following the [documentation to authorize requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing) and if you want to understand better the process to OAuth 2.0 and adjust it to your use case, then check the [documentation about using OAuth 2.0 fo access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). OAuth 2.0 is recommended, but if you want to handle the security of the keys by yourself, you can use API keys. There are different options of [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication).

Comment: This helped me! Thanks. I got the [OUTH2_TOKEN] by running "gcloud auth print-access-token" on my ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Using rest API you can download/upload files from google storage in the following way that I already did in the below-mentioned link:

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955058/4345389

Instead of UploadData method of WebClient, you can use DownloadData method in the following way:

```
// Create a new WebClient instance.
using (WebClient client= new WebClient())
{
  client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + bearerToken);
  client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/octet-stream");
// Download the Web resource and save it into a data buffer.
byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData(body.SourceUrl);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
// TODO write further funcitonality to write the memorystream
}
```

Do some tweaks as per your requirements.