# Playstore Statistics file download From google cloud storage using rest api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I turn out that google play store stores statistics related data in google cloud. It creates the required buckets and updates the file daily as it is required.
I am trying to download those file in google app script and update the Google sheet with data.

From google documentation, there are 2 ways to do so.

1. With Oauth
2. API KEY.

So far I was able to download file with Oauth but with API KEY I am getting the error

> There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API
>   key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the
>   Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if
>   request from this IP or referer should be allowed.

I have created the API KEy with no restrictions. Also enabled the Cloud Storage JSON api and Cloud storage API.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same in the following way:

Get Oauth token:

```
public string GetOAuthToken()
{
return googleCredential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth", CancellationToken.None).Result;
}
```

I am able to make a request.

Reference:

[How to download files in Google Cloud Storage using rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932534/how-to-download-files-in-google-cloud-storage-using-rest-api?answertab=active#tab-top)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955058/4345389

Thanks

Comment: Thanx Jayoti,
My question is specific to the API key, not Oauth. Although I have completed the given task using Oauth.
Secondly i was trying to do this in AppScript so resources were quite limited.