# Authorization to Google Cloud without Google Cloud SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Is it possible to authorize with Google Cloud with Service Account without using google cloud SDK? 
I'm developing integration with DialogFlow with our java project, but dialogflow java library is still on alpha (0-74.0-alpha), so, I want to integrate via custom requests.

Comment: I believe their github has sample code that tell you how to use code to authorize requests https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/auth/samples/AuthExample.java

Comment: yes, you can do authorization in the following way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196515/uploading-objects-to-google-cloud-storage-buckets-in-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top  
I did the same in DotNet.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find step by step instructions how to [set up authentication for Dialogflow.](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup). V2 of the Dialogflow API relies on a Google Cloud Platform Service Account for authentication, instead of the previously used client and developer access tokens.

Building your app in Java, you can also use [Java Google API Client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) 
Then you can [build credentials using OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2)

Here you can see [samples of the implementation of the libraries](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/auth/samples/AuthExample.java)